# Puzzling together parameters

Tags: powershell

need some help!

I have a rather difficult problem, I would like to solve. 
I have an array:

```
@array = string, string, string
```

In my example:

```
yellow, red, blabla
```

I would like to use these string from the array and put them in a commandlet with extra if-clauses (difficult to explain, I will better show it) and check if they exist before adding them to the commandlet.

```
$array = @()
$array += "red"
$array += "blabla"
$command = write-host
if ($array[0]) {$command = $command + " -foregroundcolor $array[0]"}
if ($array[1]) {$command = $command + " -object $array[1]"}
&$command
```

This obviously doesn't work. The question is, how can I have some sort of **puzzling** together certain parameters of a single commandlet with *strings?*

```
Error tells me more or less, that this no commandlet or executable script.
```

another idea I had, but I would like to **avoid**, because it won't stay simple:

```
If (!$array[0]) {
              (if (!$array[1]) {write-host "nodata"} else {write-host -object $array[1]})
else
                   (if (!$array[1]) {write-host -foregroundcolor $array[0]}
                   else {write-host -forgroundcolor $array[0] -object $array[1]})
                }
```

Got an error in there already.

Comment: Totally unclear what you're asking and your example makes no sense. What does "puzzling together certain parameters" mean?

Comment: I am sorry, that I wasn't able to be more clear about my problem. Sometimes it is hard as a non native speaker to create senseful questions about special programming problems. Despite my inability of asking properly I already got the perfect anwere. Thx for reading though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx). You create a hash which represents the name/value pairs of your parameters, and pass that into the cmdlet. This makes for a very easy way to conditionally set parameters for a cmdlet without having to copy/paste the various permutations of how the cmdlet is called within switch or nested if/else blocks.

```
$MyParms = @{};    
$array = @()
$array += "red"
$array += "blabla"
if ($array[0]) {$MyParms.Add("foregroundcolor",$array[0])};
if ($array[1]) {$MyParms.Add("object",$array[1])};

Write-Host @MyParms;
```

Comment: I would like to accept both your anwers, but to be fair, the faster one gets the approval. Thx for both your help and the insane speed! I was thinking about hours before someone would answer this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue - "I want to call a cmdlet, but with some parameters present/missing depending on various programmatic conditions."

The standard solution is to put your arguments in a hashtable, and pass them using [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx).

```
$array = @()
$array += "red"
$array += "blabla"

$params = @{}
if ($array[0]) { $params['foregroundcolor'] = $array[0] }
if ($array[1]) { $params['object'] = $array[1] }

write-host @params
```